# animationtimer javafx button won't update or refresh

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have a problem with my javafx application.

It works in just command line, but when making a javafx setup I get a problem. Every time I have a button that e.g. when clicked should hide another button, it won't update or refresh. I have been told that animationtimer should resolve my problem, but my question goes how to example refresh every time a button is clicked?

Comment: Just modify the scene. If your code isn't working, you need to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others get a chance to see the actual problems in your code. Below is an answer to your question 'how to update every time a button is clicked?'.

---

You can use an `AnimationTimer` to implement this behaviour, but the simplest solution is often to use a callback. A callback is a function that is called when the button is clicked, which you get to write. Thus you can do anything when the button is clicked.

You can set this callback by calling the `Button.setOnAction()` function. You can pass e.g. a lambda function or an `EventHandler`. Here is an example with two buttons which hide each other when clicked (as you mentioned):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class main extends Application{

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button1 = new Button("Button 1");
        Button button2 = new Button("Button 2");

        button1.setOnAction(event -> {
            // This code is executed when button1 is pressed
            if(button2.isVisible())
                button2.setVisible(false);
            else button2.setVisible(true);
        });

        button2.setOnAction(event -> {
            // This code is executed when button2 is pressed
            if(button1.isVisible())
                button1.setVisible(false);
            else button1.setVisible(true);
        });

        button2.setLayoutX(75);

        Group root = new Group(button1, button2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(150);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]

I recommend having a look at [the callback concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) and [first class functions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)
These are very useful concepts with diverse applications.